# Jvm byte code validation failing while deployment in cloud foundry, but when deployed in local using jetty, code runs fine

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-bytecode

I am deploying a war in cloud foundry, but it fails during jvm byte code validation. But when deployed in local jetty server it runs fine.

To avoid this situation I have to set noverify at the env.
Could not figure out any possible root cause.

Comment: What compiler are you using (locally), and exactly what is the error message?

Comment: Java compiler : jdk1.8.0_161